# Derivative of entropy of a mixture of random variables

Tags: probability, references, random-variable, entropy, derivative

**Setting**

Consider two random variables $X_1, X_2$ and their entropy $H(X_1), H(X_2)$. Let $V$ be a random variable which takes values $1,2$ with equal probability.

**Problem Statement**

Let $\frac{dH(X_1)}{d\theta}  = -1 $ and $\frac{dH(X_2)}{d\theta}  = -1$,
can we say that $\frac{dH(X_V)}{d\theta}  <= 0 $ ?

Comment: Do you mean $V$ takes values from $X_1$ and $X_2$ with equal prob? and what is $\theta$ ?

Comment: $X_V$ takes values from $X_1$ and $X_2$ with equal probability. P(X_v=x) = 0.5*P(X_1 = x )+ 0.5*P(X_2=x). $\theta$ is a parameter on which $X_1$ and $X_2$ depend.

Comment: I could give more details about $\theta$ but..it will make the problem messy.